# grep'ping files for multiple strings (not necessarily on the same line)

Tags: text-processing, grep

More often that I like to admit I look for a file that contains some strings.

Currently I do:

```
grep -rl string1 | xargs grep -l string2 | xargs grep -l string3
```

Is there a tool that does this prettier?

This `grep`s for `string1` or `string2` or `string3`.

```
grep -rl -e string1 -e string2 -e string3
```

I want files that contain `string1` and `string2` and `string3` but not necessarily on the same line.

Maybe one of the modern `grep`s (`ag/ack/rg/sift`) can do this?

Answer (score 8):

You could use `grep` in this way:

```
grep -rzlP '(?s)(?=.*?string1)(?=.*?string2)(?=.*?string3)' .
```

- `(?s)` Known "dot-all" which tells *grep* to allow the dot `.` to match `\n`ewline characters as well.`
- `(?=.*?pattern)`: Positive Lookahead, that matches any characters `.` that occurrences zero or more times `*` and non-greedy followed by a pattern(`string1`, `string2`, ...).

You can make a function as following (POSIX `bash` & `zsh`):

```
mgrep() { eval grep -rzlP $(printf ''\''(?s)';
          printf '(?=.*?'\''"$%d"'\'')' $(eval echo {1..$#}); printf ''\''') . ; }
```

then call as below and it will look for the files recursively within current working directory having all *patterns* in.

```
mgrep string1 string2 string3
```

it will also handle any types of patterns as `grep` itself supports (*adjust the `grep`'s option in function per your requirement in advance*).

```
mgrep string 'pattern with space' '\d+' [0-9]  [...]
```

Comment: @Fólkvangr See my solution based on αғsнιη's. It is basically just dequoting the solution here.

Answer (score 4):

With `agrep` (the original [approximative `grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agrep), not the one from `tre`), you can do

```
agrep -ld '$x' 'pattern1;pattern2;pattern3'
```

Where we use regexp that cannot match (`$x`, something after the end) as the delimiter.

(use `find` or `zsh` recursive globs to search in all files in a directory recursively).

Though note the patterns are matched against the whole content of the files, not each line of each file.

You can script it with gawk with:

```
PATTERNS='pattern1;pattern2;pattern3' gawk -e '
  BEGIN{n = split(ENVIRON["PATTERNS"], a, ";")}
  BEGINFILE{for (i in a) p[a[i]]; found = 0}
  {
    for (i in p)
      if ($0 ~ i) {
        if (++found == n) {print FILENAME; nextfile}
        delete p[i]
      }
  }' -E /dev/null file1 file2...
```

(though it's pretty slow).

Comment: This seems only to work if the whole file is a single paragraph (i.e. has no empty lines). Thus not equivalent to original solution.

Comment: @OleTange, Oh yes, you're right. I had assumed that `^$` would have worked like for gawk's `RS="^$"`, but no. See edit: `-d '$x'` should work.

Answer (score 1):

Based on αғsнιη's answer:

```
mgrep() {
    grep -rzlP "(?s)$(printf "(?=.*?%s)" "$@")" .
}

mgrep string1 string2 string3
```

Comment: This is a terrific answer. No need to even add the function to bashrc, just copy and paste it when needed. Then one can use it and refine the terms as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The following proposition is simple but could probably be more efficient and robust.

```
#!/bin/bash

tab=(one three five)

# grep_all's return status indicates if all patterns have at least
# one matching result in the text file specified as argument.

grep_all()
{
    local -n patterns=$1      # allows to refer to an array
    local file=$2

    # abort if a pattern is not found
    for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"; do
        if ! grep -q -e "$pattern" "$file"; then
            return 1
        fi
    done
}

grep_all tab file.txt
echo $?
```

Comment: It would (possibly) be handier (or at least portable) if the `grep_all` function took the pathname as the first argument and then a list of patterns. You would then `shift` the pathname off first, and then loop over `$@`.

Comment: The `grep` in his solution is definitely _not_ POSIX `grep` though.