# Grep "Pattern 2" only in files containing "Pattern 1"

Tags: grep, find

I am trying to search for a "pattern 1" only in files that contain another string "pattern 2"

E.g.

A.txt
Pattern 1
...
Pattern 2

B.txt
Pattern Z
...
Pattern 2

I intend to filter out files that match Pattern 1 in this case A.txt and then search occurrences of Pattern 2  only in A.txt.

I am trying below but doesn't work.

**grep -rl "Pattern 1" . -exec grep -or "Pattern 2" +**

Note: Some file paths include spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe to `xargs`:

```
grep -rlZ "Pattern 1" | xargs -0 grep -l "Pattern 2"
```

or use `find` and `grep -q` + `grep -l`:

```
find . -type f \
  -exec grep -q "Pattern 1" {} \; \
  -exec grep -l "Pattern 2" {} +
```

The `xargs` option is probably more performant, as it will call `grep` on multiple files at once, while the `find` will call `grep` for each file.

Comment: For the `find` variant, you can use `-exec grep -l 'Pattern 2' {} +` (and remove `-print`) to avoid some of the execs.

Comment: thanks, I was trying it, but only with first grep, that did not work ... but won't the first `grep` separate the files already ?

Comment: Ah, no, that would not work as that `grep` has to be run as an individual test on each file. The second one can run on all that passes the first test in one go though.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466101/grepping-files-for-multiple-strings-not-on-the-same-line for a form of an "and grep" for all files in a directory.